# CosmosDb Optimistic Concurrency at the *container* level?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

Plenty of articles explain how to use a document's ETag to opt into optimistic concurrency behavior for that document.

It appears that a [container itself may also have an ETag](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/account-databases-containers-items#properties-of-an-azure-cosmos-container). However, there's no explicit mention of whether that ETag reflects changes to the *documents inside* the container, or only to the definition of the *container itself*.

In short, **is it possible (and supported) to use the etag property of a CosmosDb container to prevent concurrent updates across the entire container?**

I'm similarly curious about the timestamp property. Is that updated when any document changes, or just the container itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is it possible (and supported) to use the etag property of a CosmosDb
> container to prevent concurrent updates across the entire container?

No, the `etag` property at the container level cannot be used to prevent concurrent updates across the entire container.

> I'm similarly curious about the timestamp property. Is that updated
> when any document changes, or just the container itself?

`ts` property at the container level is only updated when that container is updated. When you update a document, only that document's `ts` property gets updated not that of the container.